# How to prevent unnecessary redraws of innerHTML in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component with a list that shows the contents of an array of objects via an `*ngFor`. The list works like an accordion: by clicking on a link in a list item, the list item folds open, showing a block of HTML that's inside the list item. The HTML block is rendered with `[innerHTML]`.

The list items are either opened or closed with the property `listItem.opened`. When this happens, the **HTML block is regenerated, even though its data in `listItem.html` or visibility has not changed**!

In short: is there a way to prevent Angular from automatically redrawing elements with `[innerHTML]`?

```
<ul class="border level1" [@fold2]="'out'">
  <li class="level1" *ngFor="let item of items; index as itemIndex">
    <a class="name text-large" [class.opened]="item.opened" (click)="onSelect(item)"
      *ngIf="item.routerLink || item.html || item.children || item.items">
      {{ item.name }}
    </a>

    <!-- THIS ELEMENT IS NEVER REGENERATED BY ANGULAR WHEN THE BOOLEAN "item.opened" IS UPDATED -->
    <span class="name text-large" *ngIf="!item.html && !item.children && !item.routerLink && !item.items">
      {{ item.name }}
    </span>

    <!-- THIS ELEMENT IS REGENERATED BY ANGULAR WHEN THE BOOLEAN "item.opened" IS UPDATED -->
    <div class="content text-standard html-block" [innerHTML]="item.html | safeHtml"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why do you use `innerHTML` ?

Comment: [innerHTML]="item.html | safeHtml" keeps watching for 'item' object updates. Since item.opened changes 'item' then directive innerHTML causes redraw.

Comment: Try to assign item.html content to some other property and check if it is regenerated in that case

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I'll check if there's an alternative for [innerHTML]
@Florian: innerHTML is advised when HTML code instead of text should be displayed.